# How to set the content type of an S3 object via the SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use AWS Api to set the content type of multiple objects and to add a 'content-encoding: gzip' header to them. Here's my code for doing that:

```
for (S3ObjectSummary summary : objs.getObjectSummaries() )
   {
       String key = summary.getKey();
       if (! key.endsWith(".gz"))
           continue;

       ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
       metadata.addUserMetadata("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
       metadata.addUserMetadata("Content-Type", "application/x-gzip");
       final CopyObjectRequest request = new CopyObjectRequest(bucket, key, bucket, key)
               .withSourceBucketName( bucket )
               .withSourceKey(key)
               .withNewObjectMetadata(metadata);

       s3.copyObject(request);
   }
```

When I run this however, the following is the result:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the prefix `x-amz-meta` was added to my custom headers, and they were lower cased. And the `content-type` header was ignored, instead it put `www/form-encoded` as the header.

What can I do it to cause it to accept my header values?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found the problem. `ObjectMetadata` requires the content-type / encoding to be set explicitly rather than via `addUserMetadata()`. Changing the following:

```
   metadata.addUserMetadata("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
   metadata.addUserMetadata("Content-Type", "application/x-gzip");
```

to:

```
       metadata.setContentEncoding("gzip");
       metadata.setContentType("application/x-gzip");
```

fixed this.

Comment: It doesn't exists on SDK version 2. How could it be then?

Answer (score 3):

In SDK V2, use:

```
PutObjectRequest.builder() 
...
.contentType(contentType)
.build()
```