# Why is file uploaded with s3 (java lib) still have content type application/octet-stream

Tags: java, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Why does file uploaded with java s3 library have content type application/octet-stream
when I access it from web even though I set the contentEncoding to text/html in the code when I upload it ?

```
ByteArrayInputStream contentsAsStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(contentAsBytes);
ObjectMetadata md = new ObjectMetadata();
md.setContentLength(contentAsBytes.length);
md.setContentEncoding("text/html");
s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(ARTIST_BUCKET_NAME, artistId, contentsAsStream, md));
```

Comment: Do you want to use setContentType() instead of setContentEncoding().  [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23467253/3587167).

Comment: @James Wing ah sorry my testing was flawed that hasnt actually fixed the problem, made no difference

Comment: if I name the file so it ends with .html it does work, but I want urls without the html at the end.

Comment: @Thilo  not the same question because in this question I was inocrrectly using setContentEncoding() not setContentType(), I then fixed this coding error but it didnt resolve my issue - so I raised a new question for the new problem.