# How do I set the Content-Type of an existing S3 key with boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to update the Content-Type of an existing object in a S3 bucket, using boto3, but how do I do that, without having to re-upload the file?

```
    file_object = s3.Object(bucket_name, key)
    print file_object.content_type
    # binary/octet-stream
    file_object.content_type = 'application/pdf'
    # AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Is there a method for this I have missed in boto3?

**Related questions:**

- [How to set Content-Type on upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550816/aws-content-type-settings-in-s3-using-boto3)
- [How to set the content type of an S3 object via the SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467044/how-to-set-the-content-type-of-an-s3-object-via-the-sdk)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There doesn't seem to exist any method for this in boto3, but you can copy the file to overwrite itself.

To do this using the AWS low level API through boto3, do like this:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
api_client = s3.meta.client
response = api_client.copy_object(Bucket=bucket_name,
                                  Key=key,
                                  ContentType="application/pdf",
                                  MetadataDirective="REPLACE",
                                  CopySource=bucket_name + "/" + key)
```

The `MetadataDirective="REPLACE"` turns out to be required for S3 to overwrite the file, otherwise you will get an error message saying `This copy request is illegal because it is trying to copy an object to itself without changing the object's metadata, storage class, website redirect location or encryption attributes.`
.

Or you can use [`copy_from`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.copy_from), as pointed out by Jordon Phillips in the comments:

```
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
object = s3.Object(bucket_name, key)
object.copy_from(CopySource={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                             'Key': key},
                 MetadataDirective="REPLACE",
                 ContentType="application/pdf")
```

Comment: Copy is also in the resource. [docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.copy_from)

Comment: @JordonPhillips Even better, thanks! If you'd like to add that as an answer I'll accept that

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @leo's answer, be careful if you have custom metadata on your object.
To avoid side effects, I propose adding `Metadata=object.metadata` in the leo's code otherwise you could lose previous custom metadata:

```
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
object = s3.Object(bucket_name, key)
object.copy_from(
          CopySource={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': key},
          Metadata=object.metadata,
          MetadataDirective="REPLACE",
          ContentType="application/pdf"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `upload_file` function from boto3 and use `ExtraArgs` param to specify the content type, this will overwrite the existing file with the content type, check out this [reference](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html)

check this below example:

```
import boto3
import os

client = boto3.client("s3")

temp_file_path = "<path_of_your_file>"
client.upload_file(temp_ticket_path, <BUCKET_NAME>, temp_file_path, ExtraArgs={'ContentType': 'application/pdf'})
```

Comment: Yup, though the question was “how do I do that, without having to re-upload the file?” :)

Comment: yeah I get it, I just thought instead of making a copy and replacing , why not just reupload using a specific format